# WPF - make rounded button larger in mouse hover

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a rounded button using following code.

```
<Button Width="100"
        Height="100">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                         StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <RadialGradientBrush>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                          Color="Lime" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                          Color="Lime" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                          Color="Gold" />
                            <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

I need to make this button little bit large when mouse hover. I searched on this community and Google also. But I could not find a way to do it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to apply [`ScaleTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on rendering, when mouse is over the button.
Style triggers is a way to do this:

```
    <Button Width="100" Height="25" Content="Press me!">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5, 0.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.2" ScaleY="1.2"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Note, that you must change `RenderTransformOrigin` to scale from center instead of top left corner.

Comment: It Worked. Thanks @Dennis

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, there is no "mouse hover" event, but if "mouseover" is also okay I should be able to help with my answer. I'm just not able to test in the code, but this here should be the solution to your problem:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                         StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <RadialGradientBrush>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                          Color="Lime" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                          Color="Lime" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                          Color="Gold" />
                            <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.65" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="150"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

I simply accessed `Trigger` via `Button.Style` and change there then the properties.

Comment: While the style is a right direction, to set size directly isn't an option in most cases. This assumes, that button already has some dimensions, known at *design-time*. Usually, this isn't true, since XAML is mostly layout-oriented framework, when ultimate size of particular element is known only at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

More over, there two things you can do, while changing the aspect of a xaml control :

1 : **Change its state** : every control has a set of states (hover, released, pressed,...) attached to the properties (background color, render size,...) bound to its class. Depending on the control you're trying to modify, you can change a lot of things simply by modifying a parameter of a sub-item (let's say the size of your Ellipse, within the buttons).

2 : **Make a custom animation** : said differently, it's called a storyboard, where you define animation keys. Launched by a trigger, these animations are very useful because they're not just a simple interpolations between two states, but a real motion design.

For both of these techniques, you will probably have to modify or create tour own control Template for the buttons.